# Angular form field not binded

Tags: angular, typescript

I've a form:

```
<form #appForm>
  <div...>
    <select
      id="transversal"
      name="transversal"
      [ngModel]="app.transversal" 
      type="select"
      required
      #transversal="ngModel">
        <option value="S">Si</option>
        <option value="N">No</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</form>
```

`this.app` is:

```
@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'aplicacions-subcomponent.component.html',
    selector: 'app-aplicacions-subcomponent'
})
export class AplicacionsSubcomponentComponent {
    private app: Application;

    @ViewChild('appForm')
    private appForm: NgForm;
}
```

I'm facing with `app.transversal` is not populated when I pick an option on my select input.

I've took a look on my form on debug time. As you can see, `form.transversal` is changed, but `this.app.transversal` keeps `null`:

[image]

**I know I'm able to use (change) event. I need to solve that using above approach.**

Comment: shouldn't it be `[(ngModel)]="app.transversal"`

Comment: ngModel should be `[(ngModel)]="app.transversal"`. And can't you use `FormGroup` and `FormControl`?

Comment: You are right! Damn it! I need to be on holidays!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please take a look at your form: In your `<select>` element you're binding to 
`[ngModel]`. 
That means that you only have a one-way data binding.

In order to get a two-way data binding, please change it to 
`[(ngModel)]`.
By that the vale gets written back into the model when you select something else.

Comment: Bananas in boxes!

Comment: Correct :) See more info here: https://bytes.vokal.io/20160509-angular-data-binding/